# Fundamental group of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2$ is non-trivial.

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups, deformation-theory

> Show that $\pi_1 \left (\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2 \right )$ is non-trivial.

**My Attempt** $:$

We know that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$ deformation retracts to $S^1.$ Scaling down by any $r \gt 0$ we can deform the punctured plane to a circle of radius $r$ and the deformation is precisely given by the continuous map $H : \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \} \times I \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$ defined by $(x,t) \mapsto (1 - t) x + t \frac {r x} {\|x\|},$ $x \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$ and $t \in I.$ One can easily show that $H$ is a strong deformation retract and consequently all the points on the circle $C_r$ centered at the origin and radius $r \gt 0$ remains fixed during the homotopy. Now fix some $0 \lt r \lt 1$ and consider the loop $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}$ which traverses the circle $C_r$ once in the anticlockwise direction. Then after deformation $\gamma$ maps to itself which is a non-trivial loop in $C_r$ as $\pi_1 (C_r) \cong \mathbb Z$ and $\gamma$ corresponds to  $1 \in \mathbb Z.$ So $\gamma,$ thought of as a loop in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \},$ is non-trivial as well since $\pi_1 (C_r) \cong \pi_1 \left (\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \} \right ).$ Then it follows that $\gamma$ is non-trivial when considered it as a loop in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2$ as $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0) \}.$

Am I right with my reasoning or is there anything needs to be added? Any suggestion in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your argument, but I have always thought that an argument would be that if your loop $\gamma$ were null-homotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\Bbb{Z}^2$, it would also be null-homotopic in $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Because that is not the case we are done. More generally, removing points from a space can only make previously homotopic loops non-homotopic (when the homotopy needs one or more of the removed points to work), not the other way around. May be I'm missing something?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen$:$ This is exactly what I meant to say. If $Y \subseteq X$ and $\gamma$ is a loop in $Y$ which is null-homotopic as a loop in $Y$ then the same loop when thought of as a loop in the bigger space $X$ is null-homotopic as well because the continuous one parameter family of based loops in $Y$ which takes $\gamma$ in $Y$ towards the constant loop in $Y$ will work as a homotopy in $X$ too between $\gamma$ and the constant loop in $X$ since $Y \subseteq X.$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen$:$ This problem is given as one of the presentations to the masters students who are taking up the course on algebraic topology. So I thought it would not be that easy but it turns out that there is not much thing to do here. I am willing to know what kind of presentation, the instructor would expect in this regard? Is it all right if somebody goes along the above lines that I argued?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen$:$ Sir do you have any idea on what exactly the fundamental group of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2$ is? Can I someway use Van-Kampen's theorem? I don't know any version of Van-Kampen's theorem which is true for wedge of infinitely many copies.

Comment: No idea. Looks horrendous to me :-) Any closed path has a compact trace and hence can weave around only finitely many lattice points, but I don't know what that implies? Possibly some kind of a category-theoretical limit of the fundamental groups of the versions with finitely many punctures? You need to ask a topologist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is absolutely correct. Here is a suggestion making it a bit more "elegant".

Let $X = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2$ and $C \subset X$ be the circle with center at the origin and radius $1/2$. Let $i : C \to X$ be the inclusion.

There is a retraction $r : X \to C$ given by $r(x) = \dfrac{x}{2\lVert x \rVert}$.

Then $r \circ i = id_C$ and therefore
$$r_* \circ i_* = id$$
for the induced homomorphisms on the fundamental groups (as basepoint for both spaces $C,X$ take any $c_0 \in C)$. This makes it impossible that $\pi_1(\mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathbb Z^2) = 0$ because in that case we would get $r_* \circ i_* = 0$ which contradicts the fact that $\pi_1(C) \ne 0$.